Call in python to a constructor of a C++ class exported through SWIG using a typemap(out), creates an invalid object
Here is a minimal example.
I have the following SWIG interface file (all-in-one)
pyhello.i
%module pyhello

%{
  #include <iostream>
  
  // Inline definition of my C++ class
  class MyInt
  {
    public:
      MyInt(int n) : _n(n) {}
      
      static MyInt* create(int n) { return new MyInt(n); }
    
      int get() const { return _n; } 

    private:
      int _n;
  };
%}

%typemap(out) MyInt, MyInt&
{
  std::cout << "%typemap(out) MyInt, MyInt&" << std::endl;
  $result = PyLong_FromLongLong($1.get()); // $1 is an object or a reference
}

%typemap(out) MyInt*
{
  std::cout << "%typemap(out) MyInt*" << std::endl;
  $result = PyLong_FromLongLong($1->get()); // $1 is a pointer
}

// Export MyInt (only public stuff is needed here)
class MyInt
{
  public:
    MyInt(int n);
    
    static MyInt* create(int n);

    int get() const;
};

I compile it (under Ubuntu 22.04, g++ 11.4.0, python 3.10.12 and SWIG 4.2.0) using these two commands:
swig -c++ -python -o pyhello_wrap.cpp pyhello.i

g++ -fpic -shared pyhello_wrap.cpp `python3-config --cflags` -o _pyhello.so

Then I run the following python script:
from pyhello import *

i1 = MyInt.create(5)
print(type(i1))
print(i1)

i2 = MyInt(6)
print(type(i2))
print(i2)
print(i2.get()) # This one fails

...which produces the following output:
%typemap(out) MyInt*
<class 'int'>
5
%typemap(out) MyInt*
<class 'pyhello.MyInt'>
<pyhello.MyInt; proxy of 6 >
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/****/test_pyhello.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(i2.get())
  File "/****/pyhello.py", line 73, in get
    return _pyhello.MyInt_get(self)
TypeError: in method 'MyInt_get', argument 1 of type 'MyInt const *'

[Edit]
Executing this python instruction also lead to an error. I understand that i2 is not a valid MyInt object and not a valid integer:
>>> print(i1 + i2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'MyInt'

My questions:

Why the call to the constructor MyInt creates an invalid MyInt
object in Python (we see that the typemap is used to obtain an
integer and then the integer is wrapped into a fictive MyInt
python object)? Is there a bug in SWIG?
Is there any way to have a typemap(out) for MyInt so
that 'create' returns native integers while having a constructor of
MyInt which keeps creating proxy objects (as if there was no
typemap)?

Thank you for your help!


In SWIG Python, the constructor is affected by the same typemap as the get() method. You intercept the value it returns and replace its this with an int object. The result is an int-like object. This part is completely expected.

You can apply a typemap only to selected methods:


%typemap(out) MyInt* MyInt::create
{
  std::cout << "%typemap(out) MyInt*" << std::endl;
  $result = PyLong_FromLongLong($1->get()); // $1 is a pointer
}


Do not forget

%newobject MyInt::create;

as without it, you are creating a memory leak.

Thank you very much for your answer. A specific typemap for create might be the solution.
I assume you meant that "the constructor is affected by the same typemap as the create() method". ì2 is created using a constructor, and as you said, it should be converted into a "ìnt-like object. But this is not the case. ì2 in my example is an invalid pyhello.MyInt object : Not a real MyInt (calling i2.get() leads to an error), and not a real integer : print(i1 + i2) also leads to an error :  "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'MyInt". Is this a bug of swig ?

Yes because you can't really return something else from a constructor - it must be the object type
